# How to send mail by primary IP?

Tags: networking, nginx, email, postfix, ip

In a Debian server, I added a second IP by the following configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.1.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    gateway 1.1.1.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 1.1.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Now, `postfix` sends emails with the second IP instead of the primary IP.

I use a dedicated IP for each domain managed by `nginx`. Is it possible to send email from each domain by the IP dedicated to that domain?

If NOT, how to use the primary IP for sending emails?

Comment: Interface aliases are deprecated. As for a general solution to choose which source address the system use as a default, use `ip route change default via <your gateway> src <your prefered source address>`.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to use the IP dedicated to that domain for sending.
You need sender dependent transport maps.
Something like this:
add to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sender_maps
```

/etc/postfix/sender_maps:

```
@domain1.com   domain1_transport:
@domain2.com   domain2_transport:
```

add to /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
domain1_transport unix - - - - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 
domain2_transport unix - - - - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.2
```

Do a `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_maps` and reload postfix.
To accept mail's on both IP the best probably to have `inet_interfaces = all` in main.cf

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to send email from each domain by the IP dedicated to that domain?

Yes, you can do that. Try changing master.cf configuration file with:

```
ipaddress1:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=hostname1
ipaddress2:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=hostname2
```

Restart postfix and check send mail.